# Visual Studio 2013 Web Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a Project, that I need to run on local IIS. When I set web server's type and url in web section of Project properties, those settings are automatically written in Project file. How do I prevent this kind of behaviour and save those settings only for my local environment? There is no "Save settings for all users" checkbox or anything simmilar like in VS 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option was removed from Visual Studio 2013.  From [this Microsoft Connect page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800003/the-apply-server-settings-to-all-users-store-in-project-file-option-is-missing-in-vs2013):

> Thank you for bringing up this issue. Unfortunately, this functionality was lost when the web project properties page was refactored. We are working to get this feature back into the product.
>
> For now, if you have a project with this setting unchecked in VS 2012, and open it in VS 2013 it will respect your individual user settings until the first time that the servers section is modified on the web project properties page.

Comment: The option was reintroduced in VS 2013 Update 1.